# How to tidy data from different columns into one

Tags: r, tidyr

I'm worried that my title does not exactly capture my question.
Let me explain my issue as best as I can. This is part of my data.

```
pdpass begyr1 gvkey1 endyr1 begyr2 gvkey2 endyr2 begyr3 gvkey3 endyr3 begyr4 gvkey4 endyr4 begyr5 gvkey5 endyr5
-16348   1991  26005   1993   1994   8852   1996   1997   3708   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
-16179   2006 174876   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
-16161   1993  30964   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
-15631   1996 111491   2006     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
-14668   1988  15854   2003     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
-13980   1986  13218   1995   1996   9921   2005     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA     NA
```

Since it is a wide data so I will type in the `dput` value as well.

```
#dput

structure(list(pdpass = c(-16348L, -16179L, -16161L, -15631L, -14668L, -13980L),
begyr1 = c(1991L, 2006L, 1993L, 1996L, 1988L,  1986L), gvkey1 = c(26005L, 174876L, 30964L, 111491L, 15854L, 13218L), endyr1 = c(1993L, 2006L, 2005L, 2006L, 2003L, 1995L), 
begyr2 = c(1994L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1996L), gvkey2 = c(8852L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 9921L), endyr2 = c(1996L, NA, NA, NA, NA, 2005L), 
begyr3 = c(1997L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), gvkey3 = c(3708L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), endyr3 = c(2005L, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
begyr4 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gvkey4 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), endyr4 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_),
begyr5 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), gvkey5 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_), endyr5 = c(NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_, NA_integer_)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = "data.frame", .Names = c("pdpass", "begyr1", "gvkey1", "endyr1", "begyr2", "gvkey2", "endyr2", "begyr3", "gvkey3", "endyr3", "begyr4", "gvkey4", "endyr4", "begyr5", "gvkey5", "endyr5"))
```

I would like to to tidy it into a long format.

The `pdpass` column is the ID variable. I would like to gather all `begyrs`, `endyears`, and `gvkey` values for each `pdpass` value.
However, as you can see from the original data, some `pdpass` have only one `gvkey, endyear, begyears` values where as some have more than one. (They are indicated as `gvkey2, endyear2, begyear2, gvkey3` ... and so on).

Basically, I would like to make a row *only when the gvkey-endyear-begyear values end with the same number* for each `pdpass`

Easily put, this is my desired output:

```
   pdpass gvkeyN  gvkey begyearN begyear endyearN endyear
1  -16348 gvkey1  26005 begyear1    1991 endyear1    1993
2  -16348 gvkey2   8852 begyear2    1994 endyear2    1996
3  -16348 gvkey3   3708 begyear3    1997 endyear3    2005
4  -16179 gvkey1 174876 begyear1    2006 endyear1    2006
5  -16161 gvkey1  30964 begyear1    1993 endyear1    2005
6  -15631 gvkey1 111491 begyear1    1996 endyear1    2006
7  -14668 gvkey1  15854 begyear1    1988 endyear1    2003
8  -13980 gvkey1  13218 begyear1    1986 endyear1    1995
9  -13980 gvkey2  13218 begyear1    1996 endyear2    2005
10 -13956 gvkey1   8674 begyear1    1968 endyear2    1987    

# code
desired<-data.frame(pdpass=c(rep(-16348, 3), -16179, -16161, -15631, -14668, rep(-13980, 2), -13956),
gvkeyN=c("gvkey1", "gvkey2", "gvkey3", rep("gvkey1", 5), "gvkey2", "gvkey1"),
gvkey=c(26005, 8852, 3708, 174876, 30964, 111491, 15854, 13218, 13218, 8674),
begyearN=c("begyear1", "begyear2", "begyear3", rep("begyear1", 5), "begyear1", "begyear1"),
begyear=c(1991, 1994, 1997, 2006, 1993, 1996, 1988, 1986, 1996, 1968), 
endyearN=c("endyear1", "endyear2", endyear3", rep("endyear1", 5), "endyear2", "endyear2"),
endyear=c(1993, 1996, 2005, 2006, 2005, 2006, 2003, 1995, 2005, 1987))`
```

This is what I've tried so far

```
require(tidyr)
d1<-gather(NBER, gvkeyN, gvkey, -pdpass, -endyr1, -begyr1, -endyr2, -begyr2, -endyr3, -begyr3, -endyr4, -begyr4, -endyr5, -begyr5, na.rm=TRUE)
d2<-gather(d1, begyrN, begyear, -gvkeyN, -gvkey, -pdpass, -endyr1, -endyr2, -endyr3, -endyr4, -endyr5, na.rm=TRUE)
d3<-gather(d2, endyrN, endyear, -gvkeyN, -gvkey, -pdpass, -begyrN, -begyear, na.rm=TRUE)
d4<-arrange(d3, pdpass)
head(d4, 10)

pdpass gvkeyN gvkey begyrN begyear endyrN endyear
1  -16348 gvkey1 26005 begyr1    1991 endyr1    1993
2  -16348 gvkey2  8852 begyr1    1991 endyr1    1993
3  -16348 gvkey3  3708 begyr1    1991 endyr1    1993
4  -16348 gvkey1 26005 begyr2    1994 endyr1    1993
5  -16348 gvkey2  8852 begyr2    1994 endyr1    1993
6  -16348 gvkey3  3708 begyr2    1994 endyr1    1993
7  -16348 gvkey1 26005 begyr3    1997 endyr1    1993
8  -16348 gvkey2  8852 begyr3    1997 endyr1    1993
9  -16348 gvkey3  3708 begyr3    1997 endyr1    1993
10 -16348 gvkey1 26005 begyr1    1991 endyr2    1996
```

As you can see, I get unnecessary rows. All I need is rows where the numbers at the end of `gvkey, endyear, and begyear` exactly match. (e.g., `gvkey 1 begyr 1 endyr 1` ; `gvkey 2 begyr 2 endyr 2`; `gvkey3 begyr3 endyr3` and so on.); however, I get combinations of 1,2 and 3. Thus, row 2:9 above are all unnecessary.

Perhaps, I could somehow manually delete all the unnecessary rows after gathering. But, I thought that may be someway to make better use of the `gather` function.. I've looked at similar questions but couldn't find the solution for this problem.
Could anyone please help me with any of these solutions?

Comment: The [documentation](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/r/2904/reshaping-data-between-long-and-wide-forms#t=201607251536574365737) may also be helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can use `melt` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
melt(setDT(df1), measure = patterns("^gvkey", "^begyr", "^endyr"), 
    na.rm = TRUE, value.name = c("gvkey", "begyear", "endyear"))
```

Comment: This is brilliant. I guess I should study more on the Data.table function. Thanks